# C++ Debug Assertion Failed - vector subscript out of range on visual studio

Tags: c++, visual-studio

My code

```
while (board[x + 1][y] == '#' && x + 1 < m) x++;
```

This part is causing an error on **Visual Studio**. But, this code is working on web site for coding-test.

vector board size is 4x5.

An error occurs at x=1, y=3.

Here is a board status.

```
[0] # # # A A
[1] # # # A A
[2] # # # # A
[3] # # # A A
```

Error occurs when conditions are true.

What is a problem?

Comment: Please provide a [minimal verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example). There is no point trying to find the problem from one line of code especially as the problem may not even be that line of code.

Comment: And please select only the correct language tag. There is no `C/C++` language. `C` and `C++` are different languages.

Comment: I bet - change order of the logical expresiion:`while (x + 1 < m && board[x + 1][y] == '#' ) x++;`

Comment: I edited ```while (x + 1 < m && board[x + 1][y] == '#' ) x++;```  this code is work well!  Does visual studio prevent 'out of range'? @P__J__

Answer (score 0):

As in my comment:

```
while (x + 1 < m && board[x + 1][y] == '#' ) x++;
```

if the first logical expression is false, then (because we AND them) the second one is not evaluated and the array is not read out of the bounds.

It does not have anything in common with Visual Studio.